# Sometimes SimpleCursorAdapter column '_id' does not exist, not always. Why?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I use SimpleCursorAdapter to display information to ListView.

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.item_music,
                myCursor,
                new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID},
                // To widget ids in the row layout...
                new int[]{
                        R.id.item_artist,
                        R.id.item_album,
                        R.id.item_title,
                        R.id.item_action});
```

It sometimes works and sometime crashes with error "column '_id' does not exist". What happened?

This is my Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:344)
at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:326)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `select _id` whenever you want to select something from `database` and display to `listView`.

Eg:

```
Cursor cur =  db.rawQuery( "select _id,* from your_table", null);
```

Comment: I have used CursorLoader to get cursor, so how to use select _id as your suggestion? Thanks.